# DispatchQueue.main.async not calling escaping closure

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to understand concurrency and can't figure out why this is the escaping closure is not being called.

```
var closure: (() -> ()) = {
    defer { print("inner") }
}

func outer(asyncClosure: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    defer { print("outer") }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { asyncClosure() }
}

outer(asyncClosure: closure)

// output is "outer" only
```

Why is my escaping closure not being called? It's an async function on the main queue and is not blocking anything.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your XCode or you're testing this code in `XCUnitTest`. This code works just fine (just tested!). In `XCUnitTest`s for `@escaping` closures you have to tell the test class to wait for sometime. (search for `expectations` in Unit Tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are running this in the Playground?  The playground may "finished" running at the closing brace of outer() and the async block that comes after is not run.

Try:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```